# Getting "error: invalid use of void expression" when trying to use a function pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c89

I have two functions:

```
void A (void(*fptr)(void*))

void B(void* string)
```

In main, I am calling function A like so;

```
char* bird = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100)
strcpy(bird, "bird");

A((*B)(bird)); //error: invalid use of void expression
```

However, when I try to compile the program, I get an error when calling function A. I'm pretty certain that I am not using the function pointer correctly. Can somebody provide me some guidance?

Comment: What do you expect `*B` to be?

Comment: A pointer to a function

Comment: `A()` takes only one argument (a pointer to function). `*B` is *not* a pointer to function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your *intention* is:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void A(void(*fptr)(void*), void *ptr); // two arguments for A()
void B(void* string);


int main(void)
{
char *bird = malloc(100);
strcpy(bird, "bird");

A(&B, bird);  // OR: A(B, bird); which is the same
return 0;
}
```